# Cocos2d Sprite sheets: How to determine to which SpriteBatchNode the Sprites should be added

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to figure out how the Sprite sheets work. I found in a tutorial this code :

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *backgroundBgNode;
    backgroundBgNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"background.pvr.ccz"];
    [self addChild:backgroundBgNode];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"background.plist"];
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"MuleDeer-ipadhd.png"];
    background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    [backgroundBgNode addChild:background];
```

Basically this code is clear but suppose that I have multiple spritesheets (pvr.czz files) and that every spritesheet has hundreds of different sprites. As suggested by the previous code I should add as a child every sprite to his corresponding CCSpriteBatchNode. Basically the problem is that the tool I use to generate spritesheets will almost randomly fit the sprites in different spritesheets if all the sprites do not fit in 1 spritesheet. What I have is a list of all the files (sprites) and I don't know exactly to which spriteSheet they belong. So is there a way to get from code the right CCSpriteBatchNode to whom I should add my generating sprites ?

Answer (score 0):

The rule for using batch nodes is you can create sprites for one ONLY using the texture the batch node was initialized with.  As you say you're example should work fine but if I understand you correctly you are wondering what happens when working with more sprite sheets?  In this case you would simply duplicate what you have already done.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"myTexture1.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"myTexture2.plist"];

CCSpriteBatchNode *b = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"myTexture1.pvr.ccz"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *b1 = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"myTexture2.png"];

[self addChild:b];
[self addChild:b1];    

CCSprite *s = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"happySprite1.png"];
[b addChild:s];
CCSprite *s1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"happySprite2.png"];
[b addChild:s1];

CCSprite *s2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"slowSprite1.png"];
[b1 addChild:s2];
CCSprite *s3 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"slowSprite2.png"];
[b1 addChild:s3];
```

This code would be better suited in some functions but hopefully you get the idea?  Let me know if it's unclear still.

Comment: No. The problem is clear. I'm not wondering about what happens when more than 1 spritesheet is added. Basically the problem is that the tool I use to generate spritesheets will almost randomly fit the sprites in different spritesheets if all the sprites do not fit in 1 spritesheet. So if I have 10 spritesheets I need to determine to which SpriteBatchNode belongs happySprite1 or slowSprite2: b ?, b1 ?, b2 ? or b28. I think that I can't randomly do addChild to whathever b instance.

Comment: If sprite frames are getting adding to random textures that would be a problem for creating batch nodes for sure.  Which tool are you using?  If you can make it so you always know which frames are in which sprite sheets it would make things much simpler.  If you absolutely need to know which sprites are from which texture you can read the sprite frame plist at runtime into an NSDictionary and get a list of all the sprite frames it contains.  Then when you go to create a sprite see if it's contained in the plist.  You may even be able to query the CCSpriteFrameCache for this information.

Comment: Query the CCSpriteFrameCache ? How ?

Comment: Make a call to [CCSpriteFrameCache spriteWithSpriteFrameName].  This will return a CCSpriteFrame instance.  You can query this for the textureFileName property.  It will tell you which texture and by relation which batch node this sprite frame should be attached to.  You can then create the CCSprite using [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame].